# Foundation email template wrapper background

Tags: html, css, email, zurb-foundation, email-templates

I have a basic email template constructed using Foundation email template with Inky: http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/wrapper.html

[image]

I have a gray background color, and it looks fine when it's in full viewport. However, when I resize it down to a certain viewport, the gray background disappears and it looks odd:

[image]

Now only the header has the gray background. I want the gray background to stay consistent regardless of what the viewport is. I've tried to wrap it using a `<wrapper>` as discussed in the Inky documentation, but it doesn't work.

```
<wrapper bgcolor="#f3f3f3">
    <container>
        <row>
            //stuff here
        </row>
    </container>
</wrapper>
```

I want it to essentially look like this template where the gray background is visible still.

[image]

Comment: Can you add css to this? It's tough to tell what's causing this without seeing your rendered markup.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the **$body-background** SCSS variable in your **settings.scss**? You can see there reference [here](https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/global.html#sass-variables).

Answer (score 0):

It is working as intended. However in your case when you resize the fixed width of the email template is equal to the screen width that's why you don't see the gray background.

**You can give some `padding` of 5 or 10 to the main wrapper.**